# Javascript scroll event returns different values

Tags: javascript, html

When I add a `scroll` event listener to the `window` object in javascript, it gives different values with respect to the size of browser size when it is scrolled. Does anyone know how we can overcome this so that it gives constant values.
For example:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollAnim); 
function scrollAnim () {
    console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop);
}
```

Returns different values in the console.

Comment: ?? Hardcode a value, if you need a constant ... See [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop), different values is the idea of that property.

Comment: What are you asking? The short answer is, scrolling changes `scrollTop`, so why would you get a constant value? Are you asking for `window.innerHeight` instead?

Comment: @Teemu i dont need just one specific value. I mean when the screen is resized you get different values  from the scrollTop property

Comment: Yes, that's expected because scrolling height changes too. Can you please describe what you actually need?

Comment: Actually i need it to trigger animations using javascript so that when the user gets to a specific part of the page the animation starts